# How to write a method or function to restart the app

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a game app that, once completed, gives the option to restart. Instead of restarting each method, variable, class, etc separately, I was hoping I could just restart the whole app with the click of a button. Is there a method in swift/xcode to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not. Best way is to set up an architecture where it's easy to reset everything because all of your state is stored in one place.

For example, inside your AppDelegate/SceneDelegate (whichever architecture you're using), you could have a GameState object that controls all aspects of the game, either by directly holding all of the properties or at least being the common ancestor of everything. Then, when it's time to reset, just create a new instance of GameState().